Can the "preset device dimensions bar" of chrome DevTools be hidden?
I'd like to hide the bar that allows to select preset device sizes in chrome devtools, while keeping the Device-Toolbar. The preset bar together with some vertical spacing wastes screen estate I'd like to use.
See the attached screenshot; the yellow marked area I'd like to hide/collapse.
Is this possible somehow?

